# correct scrollViewWillEndDragging code?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

How do I get the UIScrollView to stop dragging at the end of the view, and snap it into a correct position? I've attempted using the following code, but while it correctly decelerates, and snaps into the perfect position at the top of the view, it does not allow me to scroll down:

```
 func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

        let layout = self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout

        let itemHeightIncludingSpacing = self.view.frame.height + layout.minimumInteritemSpacing

        var offset = targetContentOffset.memory

        let index = (offset.x + scrollView.contentInset.bottom) / itemHeightIncludingSpacing
        let roundedIndex = round(index)

        offset = CGPoint(x: roundedIndex * itemHeightIncludingSpacing - scrollView.contentInset.bottom, y: -scrollView.contentInset.top)
        targetContentOffset.memory = offset
    }
```

here is the top of my scroll view:

[image]

here is the the bottom, its not in the position its supposed to be as you can see. it should be flush with the bottom offset value just like the top:

[image]

how do i get the scroll to stop flush just like the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make an extension of UIScrollView that has that method? It doesn't exist but scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) does. If this is your custom method in the extension, make sure it is called somewhere in your code (like the delegate method I mentioned). Also, resetting the parameter is doing nothing to the scrollView. I would suggest a different approach.

I'm not sure what you're asking here either. Are you not wanting the content to be pulled past the edge of the screen before it bounces back in place? 
If so, you don't need that method. Just add self.myScrollView.bounces = false to viewDidLoad()

Edit:
Ok try this 

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    }

Comment: is this a collection view? also, see if my edit fixes anything for you.

Comment: is (near or at the bottom) actual syntax?

Comment: no it's not correct syntax. editing again now that I know its a collectionview

Comment: that had no effect on the scroll view

Comment: did you set self.collectionView.delegate = self ?

Comment: yes, it did nothing, i think i should be implementing a uiscrollview method rather than touching the edge insets